# Firebase or Swift text form validation?

Tags: validation, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security, text-formatting

I am working on a registration form for my app and would like to make sure that the information users enter is of the correct form. 
For example if they enter an email address, I do not want to make the SignUp button available until they enter text with the form "example@mail.com". Now, I know that Firebase can also observe the form of an email address for example. So my question is, is it better to perform the input text form validation in swift or in Firebase? 
Also in other cases such as a date text form validation is it possible to add such a rule in Firebase, then check if the text entered matches the rule?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll typically want to add validation both in your Swift code and in your server-side security rules, but for different reasons.

You *must* have validation on the server, since it is the only type of validation that malicious clients can't bypass. This validation is your last line of defense against bad data.

You'll probably also want to validate the data on the client. This is more as a service for your users: if you validate on the client, you can give them earlier (and often better) messages about whether their data is valid according to your rules.

Comment: thanks, i was suspecting this answer. So then how would go about using them simultaneously. For example, should I have swift and firebase validate each data as it's typed in (before auth), or should I only validate with swift data as it's typed in and when adding the user validating all data in firebase? One more thing, what do text form rules in firebase look like?

Comment: I have no idea what "text form rules" are, but the server-side security rules for the Firebase Database are documented [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/).